# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty

Tags: python, sqlite3, python-telegram-bot, type-error, node-telegram-bot-api

Написал код для вывода определенного ряда в Sqlite3, но при вводе в телеграмм боте Vincode выдает ошибку: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def Information(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите VINcode:')
    Vn = message.text.strip()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('cars.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM info WHERE vinkod = '{Vn}'")
    file= cur.fetchall()
    inf= ''
    for el in file:
        inf += f'VINcode: {el[0]}, Model: {el[1]}, Date: {el[2]}, Time: {el[3]}\n '

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, inf)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Как бы это не было банально, но судя по всему вы не передаете в метод send_message текст сообщения - передаете пустую строку